# my Oracle SQL want to improve a performance

Tags: sql, oracle

This code is a query that select the latest date(datetype : date) of each CID.
but this query has full scan.
CID and GATH_DTM are PK.
DATA_STAT_CODE is a flag.

I want to improve a performance.

```
SELECT CID, MAX(GATH_DTM) GATH_DTM
FROM TB_020
WHERE DATA_STAT_CODE = 28001
GROUP BY CID
```

Comment: Show us table and index definitions, and the explain plan.

Comment: The query look fine. The full table scan look fine, too. Could you run these queries and show the results for us? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_020;` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_020 WHERE DATA_STAT_CODE = 28001;` and `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CID) FROM tb_020`?

Comment: @jarlh this table has a two INDEX. 1. UNIQUE_INDEX(PK) : CID asc, GATH_DTM asc. 2. NONUNIQUE_INDEX : GATH_DTM asc

Comment: @PhamX.Bach count result is 4179537 and second is 3591336.

Comment: What about the last one `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CID) FROM tb_020`? It's the number of rows return by your query. And how long did your query run?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach the number of rows is 682. running time is about 3.166 sec.

Comment: FYI, you could refer to below answer and comment. Change your 2nd index should do the work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should add another index

```
create index idx_stat_code ON TB_020 (DATA_STAT_CODE, CID, GATH_DTM )
```

Comment: This index would improve the performance of the specific query. The question is always whether the overhead of maintaining an additional query is worth the performance improvement, which is a matter of how often the query is run.

Comment: @APC INSERT query are executed every 1 sec and SELECT query are often executed .

Comment: I modified query. `SELECT /*+ INDEX(TB_020 IDX_STAT_CODE)*/ CID, MAX(GATH_DTM) GATH_DTM FROM TB_020 WHERE DATA_STAT_CODE = 28001 GROUP BY CID`. so performance has improved a lot. thanks everybody!